# How to set camera resolution in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am working a cammera appplication to render the preview in widget.For streaming the preview i use videoWidgetSurface.
How to set the camera resolution by using QCamera class in Qt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image encoder settings using QImageEncoderSettings class. It has a function named setResolution which sets the resolution of the encoded image.

```
QCamera * camera = new QCamera;

QCameraViewfinder * viewfinder = new QCameraViewfinder();
viewfinder->show();

camera->setViewfinder(viewfinder);

QCameraImageCapture * imageCapture = new QCameraImageCapture(camera);

QImageEncoderSettings imageSettings;
imageSettings.setCodec("image/jpeg");
imageSettings.setResolution(1600, 1200);

imageCapture->setEncodingSettings(imageSettings);
```

Comment: For render the preview i'm using QAbstractVideoSurface then this surface connect to proxy widget.So how to set the camera preview resolution by using QAbstractVideoSurface.I tried setNativeResolution(resolution) API its not working.Thanks